# Mac Bash Script - Telling if a hidden folder is hidden or not

Tags: macos, bash, hidden-files

I'm using Mac OSX Lion and I would like to have a script that tells me if a directory is hidden or visible. the directory is .whatyoulookingatfool.

This is what I have now...

```
#!/bin/bash

#Check for dir
if test -d /Users/NSutton/Documents/.whatyoulookingatfool; then
    echo "go go go"
else
    echo "well shit"
fi
```

Comment: please define the `"visible"` in your understanding

Comment: Well, On mac adding the dot when using mkdir makes the file hidden. So I want to create a script that when run either makes it hidden or visible depending on its current state.

Comment: OK, this should be called hidden instead of visible. Visible mostly refer to user has enough read access, so, the folder is visible.

Comment: Changed the title so no more confusion.

Comment: The tools `dirname`, `basename`, `grep`, and `sed` would do the job. But, does it needs to be a bash script? What about Perl, Python, ...

Comment: Looks like you may be after this solution: [Tell if a folder/file is hidden in Mac OS X][1]




  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18973/tell-if-a-folder-file-is-hidden-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Looks like you may be after this solution: [Tell if a folder/file is hidden in Mac OS X][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18973/tell-if-a-folder-file-is-hidden-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any osx machine right here, but I assume that mac has a basename command and new enough bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1
bn=$(basename $dir)

if [[ -d $dir && $bn == .* ]]
then
   echo yep
else
   echo nay
fi
```

Note that this does not work with `.` and `..` directories.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpfull but I realized I'm in over my head with bash. I think I will have to come up with a hack in python.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, are you talking about files that are hidden by the Finder, or files that start with a period, so they are *hidden* on commands such as `ls` unless you specify a parameter (like `-a`) to see them?

If you're mainly talking about the dot, you can do this various ways. One is shown by [Ahe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4427/ahe). Another is this way:

if [[ ${fileName%%.*} = "" ]
   then
        echo "File name starts with period"
   else
        echo "File name does not start with period"
   fi

BTW, the square braces are the equivalent of the `test` command and is usually preferred.

Thus:

```
if test -d /Users/NSutton/Documents/.whatyoulookingatfool; then
```

is the same as

```
if [ -d /Users/NSutton/Documents/.whatyoulookingatfool ]; then
```

Note the spaces around the square braces. There are even more tests that are built into the Bash program using double square braces that can do pattern matching. See the [BASH manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) for more information.

Now, if you want to know if a file is *hidden* in the Finder. For example, `$HOME/Library` is visible in the command line tool, but is normally invisible in the Finder, you'll have to use the [GetFileInfo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/GetFileInfo.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/GetFileInfo) command. This is built into Mac OS X to see if a file is suppose to be invisible to the Finder.

There's also the `/.hidden` directory that lists all files that are hidden which was used before Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger).

Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac in front of me to run any tests, so I can't give you the exact command, but check the [GetFileInfo manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/GetFileInfo.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/GetFileInfo), and play around a bit and see how it works.

BTW, you can turn on and off the hiding of files via the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE  #Shows hidden files
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE #Hides hidden files
```

You may have to restart the Finder:

```
killAll Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

So if name exists rename to .name, and vice versa?

```
#!/bin/sh

name=whatyoulookingatfool

for f in . ''; do
    test -d "$f$name" || continue
    mv "$f$name" "${f:-.}$name"
    break
done
```